# NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/process/internal/RequestExecutorFactory

Tags: java, glassfish, runtime-error

I get this error when I send out a request with post:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/process/internal/RequestExecutorFactory
```

my code looks like that:

```
@POST
@Path("/processPayment")
public Response processPay(PaymentRequestInterface request) throws ServletException {


    Object obj = new Object();

    //create an object at the used library and do something with it

    return Response.status(status).entity(obj).build();
}
```

and if I change my POST to a GET method I get this error:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientAsyncExecutorFactory
```

maybe this information helps someone....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following dependency to your Maven project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.23</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It's another problem. If you initial question is answered, mark it as so and ask a new one on stackoverflow.