# Error: org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientAsyncExecutorFactory

Tags: java, glassfish, runtime-error

After solving this error: [NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/process/internal/RequestExecutorFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310107/noclassdeffounderror-org-glassfish-jersey-process-internal-requestexecutorfacto/38310210?noredirect=1#comment64037343_38310210)

I get now this error and I'm not sure what to do since the error just changed from an other error everything I found to this was not helpful for me

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientAsyncExecutorFactory
```

Comment: you miss a dependency again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```